# check if value exist in database array not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

need to check if the value exist in array , the array created from database table, it just not working with me keep getting error says "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given"
can someone please help ?

PHP code

```
<?php 
    $lang='en';
    $query_rsLanguages = "SELECT * FROM languages";
    $rsLanguages = mysql_query($query_rsLanguages);
    $languages_array = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsLanguages)){ 
      $languages_array[] = "\"".$row['language_sign']."\""; 
    }
    $languages_string = implode(",", $languages_array);
    if (in_array($lang, $languages_string)) {
        echo 'found' ;
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are imploding `$languages_array` to a string and passing that to `in_array`, which is incorrect and unnecessary. As the error says you need to pass an *array* to search in. You just need to build the array of languages from your result and check that:

```
<?php 
    $lang='en';
    $query_rsLanguages = "SELECT * FROM languages";
    $rsLanguages = mysql_query($query_rsLanguages);
    $languages_array = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsLanguages)){ 
      $languages_array[] = $row['language_sign'];
    }

    if (in_array($lang, $languages_array)) {
        echo 'found' ;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check if the String `$lang` exists inside your `$languages_array` or not

```
if (in_array($lang, $languages_array)) {
        echo 'found' ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above error is saying that the second parameter of the in_array should be an array, by using implode you are making it a string use the code below.

```
<?php 
    $lang='en';
    $query_rsLanguages = "SELECT * FROM languages";
    $rsLanguages = mysql_query($query_rsLanguages);
    $languages_array = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsLanguages)){ 
      $languages_array[] = $row['language_sign'];
    }

    if (in_array($lang, $languages_array)) {
        echo 'found' ;
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps you